# Generating html table from list in python

Tags: python, html, html-lists, html-table

I currently have a list of data:

```
    list = [('ALCOA INC. CDI', 66.0), ('RIO TINTO LIMITED', 29.210000000000001), ('PLACER DOME INC CDI', 18.030000000000001), ('GUNNS LIMITED', 11.609999999999999), ('ORICA LIMITED', 10.83)]
```

that's what's generated from my code, and I  want to place it into a html table, currently I can get it to only input the company name into the table, when i try to put in the numbers it just doesn't work.

```
    print '    <table border = "1" cellpadding = "1" cellspacing = "0">'
    print '         <tr>'
    for i in list:
        print '        <td>'+i[1]+'</td>' #here is where i've tried to only input the numbers, but output isn't working.
    print '            </td>'
    print '        </tr>'
    print '    </table>'
```

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

I don't really understand how I should be going about this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can't concatenate string and float types, you need to cast the float to a string:

`print '        <td>'+str(i[1])+'</td>'`

http://ideone.com/I0LJV

Answer (score 2):

or

```
print '        <td>%.2f</td>' % i[1]
```

if you want to print integer part plus 2 decimals

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations